# How to solve $u_{tt}-u_{xx} = \alpha u_t + \alpha u_x$ with given conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider

$u_{tt}-u_{xx} = \alpha u_t + \alpha u_x$

where

$\quad|x|< \infty,\;t>0$

with initial condition

$\quad u(x,0)=f(x),\; u_t(x,0)=g(x)\;$

and $\;u(x,t)=v(x,t)e^{ax+b}$

$a,b,\alpha$ arbitrary fixed

I'm new to wave equations so this might be easy question but I didn't understand how to solve. What I would do if it was something like this: $u_{tt}-u_{xx} = t^2$

Assume $v_{tt}=t^2$ then integrate twice to find $v(t)$ with given conditions. Then use transformation like $u(x,t)=w(x,t)+v(t)$ as it will be homogeneous after applying derivative twice $u_{xx}=w_{xx}$ and I have $u_{tt}=w_{tt}+v_{tt}$ then find $w(x,t)$ and new conditions for $w(x,0),w_t(x,0)$ then substitute $w(x,t)$

I tried to use same method but I couldn't make it work I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: In these types of questions, usually you would apply the product rule to $u = v e^{ax + b}$ and substitute into the original PDE. You would then simplify the problem by making a suitable choice of $a$ and $b$ (i.e here making the choice $a = - \alpha/2$ reduces the problem to $v_{tt} - v_{xx} = \alpha v_{t} - \alpha^{2} v/2 + \alpha^{2}/4$). However, you have the condition that $a, b$ and $\alpha$ are fixed, so the above choice is invalid. You would then use the Fourier transform to turn the PDE into an ODE, but you have the condition that $|x| \lt \infty$, so I'm not sure what to do.